# Hibernate5 not getting transaction with Spring5?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-5.x

I'm using Hibernate5.3 and Spring5.0.6. And I want to use `EntityManager` in JPA so this is the config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManager.setPackagesToScan("com.geniusver.model");
        entityManager.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        entityManager.setJpaVendorAdapter(hibernateJpaVendorAdapter);
        return entityManager;
    }


    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("123456");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(@Autowired EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }


    private final Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect");

        return hibernateProperties;
    }
}
```

Then I test it using Junit5:

```
@Transactional
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
class UserTest {


    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @BeforeAll
    void beforeAll() {
        entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        assertNotNull(entityManager);
        assertNotNull(entityManagerFactory);
    }

    @Rollback(value = false)
    @Test
    void persist() {
        User user = new User("testName", "password");
        entityManager.persist(user);
        entityManager.flush();
    }

}
```

And it throws `javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException`:

```
May 25, 2018 10:33:11 AM org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean buildNativeEntityManagerFactory
INFO: Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
May 25, 2018 10:33:11 AM org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionContext startTransaction
INFO: Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@84487f4 testClass = UserTest, testInstance = com.geniusver.model.UserTest@bfc14b9, testMethod = persist@UserTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@fb6097b testClass = UserTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.geniusver.Application}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@7d5508e0]; rollback [false]
May 25, 2018 10:33:11 AM org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionContext endTransaction
INFO: Committed transaction for test: [DefaultTestContext@84487f4 testClass = UserTest, testInstance = com.geniusver.model.UserTest@bfc14b9, testMethod = persist@UserTest, testException = javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress, mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@fb6097b testClass = UserTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.geniusver.Application}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]]

javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress

    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(SessionImpl.java:3545)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1442)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1438)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.flush(Unknown Source)
    at com.geniusver.model.UserTest.persist(UserTest.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:436)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:170)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:166)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:113)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:58)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:65)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: do you try   ` @Autowired EntityManager entityManager` instead of creating a new one?

Comment: @Jerry06 yes,but it throws NoSuchBeanDefinationException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you don't need to set the entityManager your self. You just need to write the `datasource` bean, and the transactionManager(JPA), entityManager will be set based on that datasource.

But your configuration seems right. The problem is how you use `EntityManager`, I think you should not create it, you should get it from context to use. If you create it yourself, you need to set datasource, set transaction manager, and maybe many other things.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I put a `@PresistenceContext` on `EntityManager` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `EntityManager` instead of `EntityManagerFactory` and put a `@PresistenceContext` on it.

```
@Transactional
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
class UserTest {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Rollback(value = false)
    @Test
    void persist() {
        User user = new User(2L, "testName", "password");
        entityManager.persist(user);
        entityManager.flush();
    }

}
```